# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 24 Incorrect syntax near 'zipcode'

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following SQL query fails at the create table line.

```
CREATE TABLE 'zipcode' (`zipcode` varchar(5),`state` char(2) ,`city` varchar(255),`lat` varchar(20),`lon` varchar(20)) 

INSERT INTO `zipcode` VALUES('00401', 'NY', 'Pleasantville', '41.075800', '-73.47300');
INSERT INTO `zipcode` VALUES('00501', 'NY', 'Holtsville', '40.485500', '-73.02400');
INSERT INTO `zipcode` VALUES('00544', 'NY', 'Holtsville', '40.485500', '-73.02400');
```

Error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '`'.
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using backticks for most things and single quotes for the table name.  Those are the escape character for MySQL.  You don't need escape characters so just write:

```
CREATE TABLE zipcode (
    zipcode varchar(5),
    state char(2),
    city varchar(255),
    lat varchar(20),
    lon varchar(20)
) ;
```

The same is true for the `insert` statements.

```
INSERT INTO zipcode VALUES('00401', 'NY', 'Pleasantville', '41.075800', '-73.47300');
INSERT INTO zipcode VALUES('00501', 'NY', 'Holtsville', '40.485500', '-73.02400');
INSERT INTO zipcode VALUES('00544', 'NY', 'Holtsville', '40.485500', '-73.02400');
```

And, why are you storing `lat` and `lon` as character strings?  These would normally be numbers.  If you want to preserve decimal places, use the `decimal()` format.

Comment: Where does 'zipcode' occur which you want to replace? please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

In addition with other answer by @Gordon sir, there's a thriftier way of writing multiple `INSERTs` as below:

```
INSERT INTO zipcode VALUES('00401', 'NY', 'Pleasantville', '41.075800', '-73.47300'),('00501', 'NY', 'Holtsville', '40.485500', '-73.02400'),('00544', 'NY', 'Holtsville', '40.485500', '-73.02400')
```